# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HttpTestSampleGui,HttpTestSampleGui2 when loading .jmx file

Tags: jmeter, classnotfoundexception

I'm getting this error when I try to load my .jmx file:

```
2016/10/13 11:20:10 WARN  - jmeter.timers.ConstantThroughputTimer: Could not convert calcMode=this thread only using Locale: fr 
2016/10/13 11:20:10 WARN  - jmeter.config.CSVDataSet: Could not translate shareMode=All threads using Locale: fr 
2016/10/13 11:20:10 WARN  - kg.apc.jmeter.threads.UltimateThreadGroupGui: Received null property instead of collection 
2016/10/13 11:20:10 INFO  - kg.apc.jmeter.threads.UltimateThreadGroup: Profile prop: null 
2016/10/13 11:20:10 INFO  - kg.apc.jmeter.threads.UltimateThreadGroup: Profile prop: null 
2016/10/13 11:20:10 INFO  - kg.apc.jmeter.threads.UltimateThreadGroup: Profile prop: null 
2016/10/13 11:20:10 INFO  - kg.apc.jmeter.threads.UltimateThreadGroup: Profile prop: null 
2016/10/13 11:20:10 ERROR - jmeter.gui.GuiPackage: Could not get GUI for http://MyURL java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HttpTestSampleGui,HttpTestSampleGui2
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.getGui(GuiPackage.java:212)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addComponent(JMeterTreeModel.java:153)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:129)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:129)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:121)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.addSubTree(GuiPackage.java:495)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:193)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:131)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:102)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doAction(Load.java:89)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

2016/10/13 11:20:10 WARN  - jmeter.gui.action.Load: Unexpected error java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addComponent(JMeterTreeModel.java:154)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:129)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:129)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.tree.JMeterTreeModel.addSubTree(JMeterTreeModel.java:121)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage.addSubTree(GuiPackage.java:495)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.insertLoadedTree(Load.java:193)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:131)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.loadProjectFile(Load.java:102)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.Load.doAction(Load.java:89)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.performAction(ActionRouter.java:81)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter.access$000(ActionRouter.java:40)
    at org.apache.jmeter.gui.action.ActionRouter$1.run(ActionRouter.java:63)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

2016/10/13 11:20:11 INFO  - kg.apc.jmeter.threads.UltimateThreadGroup: Profile prop: null
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

Your test plan is using a third party plugin kg.apc.
Be sure you have the plugin jars in  lib/ext and their dependencies in lib